# Como retornar o json_encode?

Tags: php, android, json

Preciso retornar um select feito em PHP. Ele está funcionando normalmente, mas na hora de exibir o resultado ele me retorna um erro no fim. Eu preciso retornar um `json_encode` para o *android* reconhecer. Segue a programação abaixo

```
mysql_connect('maquina','aa','senha');
mysql_select_db('aaaa') or die (mysql_error());



$Cod_Empresa = $_GET['aaaa'];
$UC = $_GET['sss'];
$di = $_GET['dddd'];
$df = $_GET['ssdddd'];
$tensao  = strtoupper($_GET['eeeeeeeeeeeee']);

if (($di != "") && ($df != ""))
    {
        $periodo = '
        && D.Mes_Ref >= "'.$di.'"
        && D.Mes_Ref <= "'.$df.'"
            Order By Mes_Ref DESC
                ';
    }
else
    {
        $periodo = '
            Order By Mes_Ref DESC
            Limit 0,12
                ';
    }
switch($tensao)
    {
        case 'BT':
            $tensao_ = "";
            break;
        case 'AT':
            $tensao_ = "
                && D.Tip_Fatur = 0
                && D.Classe in ('A1','A2','A3','A3a')
            ";
            break;
        case 'MT':
            $tensao_ = "
                && D.Tip_Fatur = 0
                && D.Classe in ('A4','As')
            ";
            break;
        case 'ML':
            $tensao_ = "
                && D.Tip_Fatur = 1
            ";
            break;
    }



switch($tensao)
{
    case 'BT':
        $sql = "SELECT Mes_Ref, round(Total_Fatura,2) as Valor_em_Reais                                                 
                FROM Tab_Fatura_BT D
                    WHERE Cod_Empresa = ".$Cod_Empresa."
                    && Cod_UC = ".$UC."                     
                            ".$periodo."    
                                            ";
                                        break;
    default:
        $sql = "SELECT  D.Mes_Ref,round(V.Valor_Total_cor,2) as Valor_em_Reais                                  
                FROM Tab_Fatura_Dados D, Tab_Fatura_Valores V, Tab_Fatura_Leituras L
                    WHERE D.Cod_Empresa = ".$Cod_Empresa."
                    && D.Cod_UC = ".$UC."
                    && V.Cod_Empresa = D.Cod_Empresa
                    && V.Cod_UC = D.Cod_UC
                    && V.Cod_Fatura = D.Cod_Fatura
                    && L.Cod_Empresa = D.Cod_Empresa
                    && L.Cod_UC = D.Cod_UC
                    && L.Cod_Fatura = D.Cod_Fatura
                        ".$tensao_."
                            ".$periodo." 
                                            ";
                                        break;
}

            $query = mysql_query( $sql ) or die('Could not query');     

        for($rows = array(); $row = mysql_fetch_array($query); $rows[] = $row);
                {   

                    linha 99 $rows[] = $row->Mes_Ref;
                    linha 100 $rows[] = number_format($row->Valor_em_Reais,2,'.',',');
                    echo json_encode($rows);
                } 

?>
```

Isso me retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: Imagem tirada do erro]

Comment: Ola, Tente fazer "echo json_encode($rows);" após o for

Comment: Me retornou o mesmo erro!

Comment: Qual é a linha 99 e 100 ?

Comment: São essas duas  $rows[] = $row->Mes_Ref;
   $rows[] = number_format($row->Valor_em_Reais,2,'.',',');

Comment: se apenas exibir o json_encode  sem as linhas 99 e 100   ele me retorna corretamente.. mas porem eu preciso tratar essas linha para me retonar um valor mais apresentavel...  mas com essas duas linhas ai  me gera um errro  apresentado acima..

Comment: troque $row->Mes_Ref para $row[Mes_Ref] e $row[Valor_em_Reais].

Answer (score 0):

O erro pode estar em seu php, verifica ai no código se o nome, senha e endereço do bd. da uma olhada se ta td certo...nesse site www.hostinger.com vc pode subir seu php e fazer seus testes em domínio real e gratuito. comigo deu o mesmo erro e o problema era o nome de uma tabela no código php...